# Can't print output with single calculation calculator

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a calculator that just multiplies two numbers together and outputs the result on the same page. Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I'm missing because I haven't been able to find it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<link type="css/text", rel="stylesheet", href="calculatorsh.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>This is a calculator that multiplies two numbers together.</p>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <p><label>First Number:<input type="text" name="number1" /></label></p>
    <p><label>Second Number:<input type="text" name="number2"/></label></p>
    <input type="submit" value='Calculate'/>

    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    Result:

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['number1'])) && (isset($_POST['number2'])){
    $number1=$_POST['number1'];
    $number2=$_POST['number2'];
    $a=$number1*$number2;
    echo $a;
    }
    ?>

</div>  

</body

</html>
```

Comment: Just for argument's sake; `</body` was that just a bad paste? Someone wants to add that missing `>` in a pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15610647 - if your code does not have the missing `>` for it, the edit should be rejected, or rolled back if it's accepted.

Comment: Btw; your code will fail if someone enters anything other than a number. You should also be using `!empty()` and not `isset()`.

Comment: are you looking at comments here?

Comment: `<link type="css/text", rel="stylesheet", href="calculatorsh.css"/>` there shouldn't be commas in there.

Comment: I obviously either have fallen onto deaf ears or you don't like me. Voting to close and moved on. I asked for clarification, I got "zilch". It's like pulling f'ing teeth.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the extra parentheses in your if statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['number1']) && isset($_POST['number2'])){
    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    $a = $number1*$number2;
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: do you see any other problems because I still dont get any output?

Comment: @factorymark There's nothing wrong with the code if you implement the changes I made. I ran it on my own server and it worked fine.

Comment: the OP's not looking at my comments under the question or isn't bothering.

Comment: @factorymark different system? you running this off a server or as `file:///`? what was posted should work here.